# Swapping views within a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a list of card view items in a recycler view. This is all within a fragment. I'd like to implement a feature where a user taps on one of the cards and it's replaced with another card in the same view. Initially i thought this could be a fragment but i'm having difficulty pulling this off and also wouldn't want to get confused as there would be more life cycles than i would like to deal with. Is there an easier way to pull this off by any chance?

Image of what i'd like to do here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEz8D.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecyclerView already implement thee feature in fact what you need to do is change the data (that you use to create the cardview) at the position clicked by the user and after that call "YourAdapterInstance".notifyDataItemChange(position) and the adapter will reflect automatically the change